# Sending push notifications to Mobile application with GCM SDK through FCM service

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Our company provides a mobile application as addon to an onpremise product. We have built a web service to send push notifications to that application through both *GCM* and *FCM*.

Around 2 years ago the mobile app was updated to utilize the *FCM SDK*. This means any client version afterwards utilizes *FCM*.

However, a large portion of the clientbase do not update the application - so we still see large percentage traffic from devices with the GCM SDK. This is a problem since GCM will be turned off very soon.

We have checked Google's documentation but we don't find this case covered there - and we have trouble testing ourselves as the device cannot get a new token from GCM. 
We want to be sure there is no way to support GCM SDK devices before communicating with end customers.

**In short:**

Is there a known way to send push notification through **FCM's** service to an app that works with **GCM SDK's Notifications**?

Comment: Maybe you want to request your users to update the app before through GCM before it shutdowns?

Comment: This is what we plan to do. However, we want to be sure there is no other option for GCM clients due to how update averse our clients are. We found documentation lacking in this case so knowledge from the field would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer and close this - we ran several tests and it was **not** possible to send a notification to a GCM SDK device using FCM services in any way.

Now that GCM is deprecated and offline, this no longer matters.